# Can I use a PC gamepad with OSX Steam games?

Tags: steam, macos, controllers

Will a PC gamepad work with all the key mappings for games in Steam on OSX?  Would getting a Microsoft 360 gamepad work on OSX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many programs that convert gamepad actions into keyboard presses such as: [Xbox HID Driver for Mac OS X](http://xhd.sourceforge.net/) and [Game pad companion](http://www.carvware.com/gamepadcompanion.html). All you need to do is set them up so that the buttons correspond to the in game actions you want them to do and you can control any game from and game pad.

Comment: these are windows programs, no?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Yeah sorry, I could have sworn XPadder was mac too, but apparently not.

Comment: no problem. That driver seems to do what Lawrence actually wants, I guess

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, Ronan. Let me give it a try and I will get back to approving the answer once I got it working.  Really ashame that there is not a trial version for Gamepad Companion (Don't think they have trial functionality on Mac App Store)

Comment: What the HID is supposed to to is provide standard interfaces to various devices so that an application only has to be aware of the Joystick HID to be able to use any HID complaint joystick/controller or any controller with an HID compliant driver.